# Is it possible in notepad++ to show markers of XML-like file to show in separate lines?

Tags: notepad++, xml

Is it possible to show 'XML-like' text, i.e. `Date:2017-03-13 12:20:20 Message: </xml><detail1>1</detail1><detail2>2</detail2></xml>` show up like this:
`Date:2017-03-13 12:20:20 Message: 
<xml>
    <detail1>1</detail1>
    <detail2>2</detail2>
</xml>`
I have txt files with messages in that format and it's quite hard to read.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Save a copy of the file as xml and open the copy.

Comment: Unsure if it'll work on a text file but try  'Notepad++ -> Plugins -> XmlTools -> Pretty print (Xml only with line breaks)'

Comment: @djsmiley2k thank you, it's good enough for me. Post it as answer, so I can close the question properly.

Comment: Glad that fixed it for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure if it'll work on a text file but try 'Notepad++ -> Plugins -> XmlTools -> Pretty print (Xml only with line breaks)'